# How does 'ssh user2@host2:user1@host1' work?

Tags: ssh

In a setup that I have inherited, using the command `ssh user2@host2:user1@host1`, I can connect to user2@host2 through user1@host1 but I don't understand how it works (where is this ssh behaviour documented?)

Furthermore, I'd like to be able to setup my .ssh/config so that I can do ssh user2@host2 and it goes directly through the host1 and I believe it can be achieved using ProxyCommand but the following is a failure:

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand='ssh -W %h:%p user1@host1' user2@host2
user1's password:
Received disconnect from REDACTED_IP: 11: Bye Bye
Disconnected from REDACTED_IP
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Answer (score 1):

I inputted the information into `.ssh/config`.

I access my `hal` server via the `jump` server using the following:

```
Host hal.serverexample.com
    ProxyCommand ssh jump.serverexample.com exec -W %h %p
    Port 22
    User user1
```

Then when I type `shh hal.serverexample.com` into terminal it asks for my password and then logs in.